# Why these kernel symbols locate in user space according to /proc/kallsyms?

Tags: linux, kernel, symbols, memory-address

I am confused with these symbols' address while I am learning linux kernel. 
Why the symbol sys_call_table locate in 0x8000e348 which should be user address space?

```
/ $ cat /boot/System.map |grep sys_call_table
c0013fe8 T sys_call_table
/ $ cat /proc/kallsyms |grep sys_call_table
8000e348 T sys_call_table
```

Meanwhile, I also want to know why there are some symbols locate around 0x000010000 according to /boot/System.map. Here are some examples:

```
00000000 t __vectors_start
0000000c A cpu_arm926_suspend_size
00001000 t __stubs_start
00001004 t vector_rst
00001020 t vector_irq
000010a0 t vector_dabt
00001120 t vector_pabt
```

And this is some system information.

```
/ $ uname -a
Linux (none) 3.11.4 #13 SMP Fri Jul 11 00:48:31 PDT 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for any help:)